# mediawiki ldap_domains does not exist and can not work

Tags: ldap, mediawiki

I am using [mediawiki](/questions/tagged/mediawiki) to build a knowledge management platform,and I want to using LDAP to implements the authencation, I am using[LDAP_Authentication](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLDAP_Authentication) to realize it.Below is my configuration code block for it:

```
require_once( "$IP/extensions/LdapAuthentication/LdapAuthentication.php" );
#require_once 'includes/AuthPlugin.php';
$wgAuth= new LdapAuthenticationPlugin(); ## 这两行激活插件

$wgLDAPDomainNames = array( "feihu" ); ##域名简写
$wgLDAPServerNames = array( "feihu"=>"10.123.123.33" ); ##域控域名或者ip
$wgLDAPSearchStrings = array( "feihu"=>"main=USER-NAME@feihu" ); ## USER-NAME 不要修改它

$wgLDAPBaseDNs = array( "feihu"=>"dc=feihu,dc=com");
$wgLDAPSearchAttributes = array( "feihu"=>"sAMAccountName"); ##加上这两句就可以把DC上的用户名都同步过来了。

$wgLDAPUseLocal = true; ## 是否使用本地用户
$wgLDAPUpdateLDAP = true;
$wgLDAPMailPassword = true;

$wgMinimalPasswordLength = 1;
$wgLDAPEncryptionType = array("feihu"=>"clear");
```

when I start my mediawiki,I can found the **LDAP_Authentication** plugin has successfully installed,but when I tried to login the mediawiki page using data from **LDAP** system, it always shows that the passoword is incorrect and please try again. and I have found that the table **ldap_domains** table does not exist in my mediawiki database.Anyone could help me to anlysis and solve this problem will be very thanksful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't run the database upater after installing the extention

In your mediawiki install dir: php maintenance/update.php

Comment: Yes,I solved this problem several months ago,but will still support your answer to add your reputation!